# OpenVPN on same server with proxy

Tags: proxy, openvpn, ip

I have OpenVPN server with clients with static IPs (192.168.1.0/24). When I access another device connected to VPN I get desired 192.168.1.2 static IP, however when I access proxy server on same machine via DNS I get my machine real IP without VPN. Simpler: I connect my laptop to VPN at example.com, I try access sub.example.com and from sub.example.com I see not my VPN static IP, but my real IP (provided by ISP). How to fix that so I see my VPN static IP from that subdomain site?

Here is my openvpn.conf:

```
server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/...
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/...
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
client-to-client
client-config-dir ccd
topology subnet
proto udp
port 22
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log
user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
route 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0

push "topology subnet"
push "comp-lzo no"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.3"
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "route 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by configuring my DNS server to route desired query to local proxy address, e.g. `10.1.0.2 sub.domain.com`, this makes it so requested traffic goes to local server via VPN's local ip, so my proxy thinks it is being accessed from `10.1.0.4` - ip of VPN server. FYI it can also be done by modifying `hosts` file on your machine, too.